# How to prevent Sequelize MySQL derived table record from deleting when the parent table record is being deleted?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, sequelize.js, cascading-deletes

- Currently working with Sequelize and MySQL dialect. There are two
  tables **BaseTable** and **DerivedTable**. Where the ***id*** from
  Base table is used as **Foreign Key** in **Derived Table.**
- Now I'm deleting record on **Base table** it automatically remove records from **Derived table** where the records are dependent through foreign key constraint.
- The question is:

> How to prevent those record in **Derived table**, even the **Base Table** record got deleted?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have cascading enabled ({onDelete: ‘CASCADE’} setting)? If so, please delete it.

Comment: Yes I have deleted it. After that do I need to change any configurations?

Comment: yes, it's required to also apply corresponding migration so that table's 'ON DELETE' has 'NO ACTION' value. 
Or you can alter BaseTable like following manually:
<pre> <code>
ALTER TABLE `test_on_delate_cascade`.`parent` 
DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_parent_1`;
ALTER TABLE `test_on_delate_cascade`.`parent` 
ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_parent_1`
  FOREIGN KEY (`child_id`)
  REFERENCES `test_on_delate_cascade`.`new_table` (`id`)
  ON DELETE NO ACTION
  ON UPDATE NO ACTION;
 </code></pre>
Or
If there is no nessesary data stored just remove tables and create again

Comment: Alright, If I don't want to delete derived records I must have to mention onDelete="NO ACTION"? Am I getting it correct?

Comment: As I have tested with all 4 onDelete constraints, only SET NULL will keep those derived table records but with the NULL value. What should I do if I want to keep this value as previous? Is there any Way?

Comment: Will you please update your answer with SET NULL is the solution to prevent data from deletion while having foreign key constraint. So it'll be helpful to others too.